# Convert Obj-C to Swift

Tags: uitextfield, swift2, overriding

Trying to override drawPlaceholderInRect in Swift2.1 so that I change the text color and I am having a hard time converting the following Obj-C to Swift:

```
(void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *colour = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if ([self.placeholder respondsToSelector:@selector(drawInRect:withAttributes:)]) {

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour, NSFontAttributeName: self.font};
    CGRect boundingRect = [self.placeholder boundingRectWithSize:rect.size options:0 attributes:attributes context:nil];
    [self.placeholder drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, (rect.size.height/2)-boundingRect.size.height/2) withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

I got this:

```
public override func drawPlaceholderInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let textDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

Can someone help out please?

Answer (score 1):

```
func drawPlaceholder(in rect: CGRect) {

    let colour: UIColor? = UIColor.white

    if placeholder.responds(to: Selector("drawInRect:withAttributes:")) {

        let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour, NSFontAttributeName: font]

        let boundingRect: CGRect = placeholder.boundingRect(with: rect.size, options: [], attributes: attributes, context: nil)

        placeholder.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: (rect.size.height / 2) - boundingRect.size.height / 2), withAttributes: attributes)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-ID0

Also, if you have trouble translating Objective-C to Swift, which can be tricky sometimes, consider overriding the method in a derived Objective-C class and then using that class in Swift.